# charging boat battery

Tags: battery, charging, boat

I have a heavy (65 lb) battery for my boat & live upstairs (no elevator) in a condo.

I don;t wanna keep bringing it inside to charge it & the only power plug I have outside is where I park my car.  There is no power where I store the boat.

I have 2 cars, so could always take the good battery out of the car & put the dead battery in &  charge it that way.  What do u suggest?

Thank u

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is there any sunshine where you store your boat? If so, you could always purchase a photovoltaic charger and attach it to the battery. As far as the battery itself goes, if it's used for a trolling motor, it's going to be a deep cycle type, which is not what is used in an automobile, so you couldn't just exchange it. You need *some sort of charger* on it.

Comment: Another possibilty compared to a pv panel is a split charge system in the car - which would mean you have to lug the battery to the car but it would keep it charged...

Comment: How often do you use your boat? If it's often, you may not need any separate charging. However, I don't see bringing the battery to your condo a problem; I used to live in 5th floor with no elevator and carried my car battery indoors when it needed charge. Some safety nazis, however, may have something against charging a flooded battery indoors. For seasonal uses, you could bring the battery indoors for the winter and have a trickle charger.